# How to Detect the Mouse Pointer Come From When Hover Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask how to detect the mouse pointer come from using jquery when the pointer hover an element like div.

When run the function I want to know mouse pointer come from top, left, bottom and right

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any attempts / thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Comment: I found a website where he have a picture grid and when i hover the picture some text showed using effect slide. but slide from mouse point come. like pointer come from top. the effect is slide down

Comment: You want to check the mouse-position onmouseenter-event inside the element, then you check whether the cursor is nearest to the top, left, right or bottom. If you know where it's nearest, you'll know what animation to use. Come back when you tried it with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var getDirection = function (ev, obj) {
    var w = obj.offsetWidth,
        h = obj.offsetHeight,
        x = (ev.pageX - obj.offsetLeft - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
        y = (ev.pageY - obj.offsetTop - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
        d = Math.round( Math.atan2(y, x) / 1.57079633 + 5 ) % 4;

    return d;
};

$('#yourDiv').mouseover(function (event) {
    var direction = getDirection(event, this);
    if (direction == 0) {
        $(this).html('Top side');
    } else if (direction == 1) {
        $(this).html('Right side');
    } else if (direction == 2) {
        $(this).html('Bottom side');
    } else if (direction == 3) {
        $(this).html('Left side');
    }
});
```

```css
#yourDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourDiv"></div>
```

`getDirection` copied from [this page](https://css-tricks.com/direction-aware-hover-effects/) by CSS-Tricks which seems to do a similar thing to what you want in a number of different ways.

Comment: It seems you flipped 'up' and 'down'.

Comment: @Bronzdragon Updated to clarify.